# Allowing a custom macro in #ifdef check

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Imagine I have some "assert like" functionality, which declares a macro one way if a specific macro is defined, and a different way if it is not:

```
// in some header assert2.hpp

#ifdef NO_ASSERT2
#define assert2(x)
#else
#define assert2(x) assert2_handler(x);
#endif
```

Here, the `NO_ASSERT2` macro is very much like the `NDEBUG` macro in standard [assert(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html).

What I'd like to do, however is allow the user to override the `NO_ASSERT2` check with their own macro, before including the file. E.g., if you included `assert2.hpp` like this:

```
#define NO_ASSERT_KEY NO_ASSERT_CUSTOM
#include "assert2.hpp"
```

Then the macro `NO_ASSERT_CUSTOM` would be checked instead of the default `NO_ASSERT2` for this translation unit.

It doesn't have to work exactly like the above - I just need some way to override the behavior on a per-file basis, without needing more than the 1 line of boilerplate shown above at the location of the include.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen in the second case, where you've defined `NO_ASSERT_KEY`?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso in that case, if `NO_ASSERT_CUSTOM` is defined (e.g., via `-DNO_ASSERT_CUSTOM` on the compile command line), then the `assert2` definition will be the dummy one, just as if `NO_ASSERT2` was defined in the original example. I.e., `NO_ASSERT_CUSTOM` takes the place of `NO_ASSERT2`.

Comment: when `NO_ASSERT_KEY` is defined, we will always check `NO_ASSERT_CUSTOM`, or do we check whatever value `NO_ASSERT_KEY` is defined as?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso - the latter: when `NO_ASSERT_KEY` is defined, you check the macro whose _name_ is the value of `NO_ASSERT_KEY`. Or some other mechanism: it doesn't have to work exactly like that (but there must be more than just one custom key, i.e., just checking `NO_ASSERT_CUSTOM` doesn't cut it).

Comment: Christ this is tough. I don't know how to do that kind of indirection in the preprocessor unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't pretty... but this approach may work for you.  It assumes that the macro is defined using either `#define FOO`, `#define FOO 1`, or `-DFOO` (assuming as typical that this creates something equivalent to `#define FOO 1`).

```
#define SECOND(...) SECOND_I(__VA_ARGS__,,)
#define SECOND_I(A,B,...) B
#define GLUE3(A,B,C) GLUE3_I(A,B,C)
#define GLUE3_I(A,B,C) A##B##C
#define AGLUE3(A,B,C) AGLUE3_I(A,B,C)
#define AGLUE3_I(A,B,C) A##B##C
#define TEST_ASSERT_KEY GLUE3(NO_ASSERT_PROBE,0_,NO_ASSERT_KEY)
#define NO_ASSERT_PROBE0_NO_ASSERT_KEY AGLUE3(NO_ASSERT_PROBE,0_,NO_ASSERT2)
#define NO_ASSERT_PROBE0_  ,1
#define NO_ASSERT_PROBE0_1 ,1
#define NO_ASSERT_TEST SECOND(TEST_ASSERT_KEY,0)
```

With this, your usage would be:

```
#if NO_ASSERT_TEST 
#define assert2(x)
#else
#define assert2(x) assert2_handler(x);
#endif
```

Here's a demo at [stacked-crooked](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60d4189d74ec9adc).

This uses pattern matching in the preprocessor via the indirect `SECOND` macro.  The idea is that it expands to its second argument, but only indirectly... this allows you to construct as the first argument a pattern.  Usually that first argument's ignored, but if you want to match something you can set it up to where the first argument would be a macro that expands with a comma; that shifts a new second argument in, replacing the default.

From here it's easier to explain backwards.  `NO_ASSERT_TEST` uses `TEST_ASSERT_KEY` to construct a pattern with a default of `0`.  `TEST_ASSERT_KEY` builds `NO_ASSERT_PROBE0_` concatenated with `NO_ASSERT_KEY`.  When `NO_ASSERT_KEY` is defined, this would build `NO_ASSERT_PROBE0_` concatenated with the expansion of what it's defined as.  Otherwise it rebuilds the test token using `NO_ASSERT_PROBE0_` concatenated with `NO_ASSERT2`.

Either way this is an indirect paste, so `NO_ASSERT_KEY` in the former case or `NO_ASSERT2` in the latter is expanded first.  In the former case, if say `NO_ASSERT_KEY` is `NO_ASSERT_CUSTOM` and `NO_ASSERT_CUSTOM` is not defined, this builds `NO_ASSERT_PROBE0_NO_ASSERT_CUSTOM`, which is just a normal identifier, which will be ignored, which results in `0` due to the `SECOND` in `NO_ASSERT_TEST`.  But if `NO_ASSERT_CUSTOM` is defined per `#define NO_ASSERT_CUSTOM`, this produces `NO_ASSERT_PROBE0_`, which expands to `,1`, which shifts `1` into the `SECOND` call in `NO_ASSERT_TEST`.  Likewise if `NO_ASSERT_CUSTOM` is defined per `-DNO_ASSERT_CUSTOM` on the command line, that would (typically) make its definition equivalent to `#define NO_ASSERT_CUSTOM 1`, which would produce `NO_ASSERT_PROBE0_1`, which expands to `,1`.

The cases for when `NO_ASSERT_KEY` is not defined are similar.

There's probably a prettier way to build this construct, if anyone wants to take a shot.